# How to redirect the APIs and the user at the same time?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I'm trying to build a tiny NodeJS server to both redirect the API calls from the user with express (the calls are made with /api and redirected to my backend) and at the same time redirect the user who visits the main page to `static/index.html`, that contains all my code (a web app).

Locally it seems to work (even with the error I am pasting you below, that happens every time an API call is made, it seems like the call is correctly redirected with the proxy but then the server tries again to redirect it to `static/index.html` and prints an error) and on the web I get a 502 error. API_URL and my personal paths not shown in code for privacy.

```
const handler = require('serve-handler');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const rewrite = require('express-urlrewrite')
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.use('/api', proxy(API_URL));
app.use('', express.static('static'));
app.use(rewrite(/.*/, '/'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'));
});

module.exports = app
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
    at server.js:22:16
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at node_modules/express-urlrewrite/index.js:60:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: const path = require('path'); -> it seems you are not including this module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path) module like,

```
const path = require('path');
```

By including this it provides utilities for working with file and directory paths.

Comment: Worked, thanks: it was the solution to the `ReferenceError`, but the 502 was caused by something else unrelated to path redirection.